# Is there a way to make CSS animation work diagonally?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have made a CSS animation that will animate the text give a shine effect to it. The effect currently only works with horizontal. I was wondering is there a way that I could change the direction of the animation to make it look like a realistic diagonal shine?

Here is my current code:

```
h1 {

font-family: 'BebasRegular', sans-serif;
font-size: 150px;
padding-bottom: 100px;
padding-top: 50px;
background: #E9AB17 -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#e8a917), to(#f4b011), color-stop(0.5, #fff)) 0 0 no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: 155px;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-animation-name: shine;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;    
}

@-webkit-keyframes shine
{
0%
{
background-position: top left;
}
28%,100%
{
background-position: top right;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change top to bottom in the ending position:

```
@-webkit-keyframes shine
{
0%
{
background-position: top left;
}
28%,100%
{
background-position: bottom right;
}
}
```

However, most probably the effect will be little noticeable. The reason is that this is a block element, and most probably it extends to the right far beyond the end of the text. So, the diagonal is quite flat. You can check this removing the

```
-webkit-background-clip: text;
```

property; you will see now all the h1 and the background movement.

To make it more "diagonal", you need to make it less "wider"; the easier way could be just specify a width.

Also, if you want to make a shine effect, I would choose a radial gradient instead of a linear one. If you don't know it, check [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) and in orientation choose radial

By the way, your question sounds familiar to me :-)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@keyframes shine {
    0% {
        transform: translatex(0px) translatey(0px)
    }
    100% {
        transform: translatex(100px) translatey(100px);
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ExjsD/)

[MDN translate documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#translate)